# How do I center an Image view in an anchor pane?

Tags: java, user-interface, imageview, javafx, scenebuilder

I am using scene builder to create my GUI and I am displaying `Image`s as users select items in a list. The `Image`s are of different sizes and when an `Image` that is smaller than the pane it is in, the image is displayed in the top left of the pane. How do I go about getting the `ImageView` and/or `Image` to be displayed in the center of the `Pane`?

I've looked throughout the javafx imageview and image APIs but I haven't found much on centering the `ImageView`in a `Pane`. I haven't seen anything in scene builder, either. Usually in scene builder, if there is a way to center a node, there will be an option for centering.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In any kind of pane its now possible to set image alignment in specific postion.. for this you can use try `HBox`

when you insert an `Image` into the `HBox`, initially its shown like below.

[image: screenshot]

now set the alignment property of the `HBox`

[image: screenshot]

now change the alignment to centre and see the output

[image: screenshot]

I hope its work for you

Its also possible to do so programmatically in a `Pane` via get image

try this

```
AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
Image img = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Edit-Male-User-icon.png"));
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(img);
anch.getChildren().add(imageView );
ImageView app = (ImageView) (Node) anchorPane.getChildren().get(0);
app.setX(100);
app.setY(100);
```

Comment: Is the hbox fitted to parent?

Comment: @jwill yes offcouse i am edit answer you can also do it programtically by using pane... see the changes

Comment: For your example, how would you keep the image centered, but also image at the top of the pane?

Comment: sorry, but the code example makes no sense to me, it does not center anything and contains redundant lines

Answer (score 7):

Create a `Group` and scene in your start method:

```
Group root = new Group();
Scene scene = new Scene(root, 551, 400, Color.BLACK);
primaryStage.setScene(scene);
```

Create an `ImageView` and set the following properties:

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
// set aspect ratio
imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);
// resize based on the scene
imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
imageView.fitHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
```

Create a `StackPane` (at least that is what I used) and bind your properties:

```
StackPane stack = new StackPane();
stack.getChildren().add(imageView);

    stack.translateXProperty()
            .bind(scene.widthProperty().subtract(stack.widthProperty())
                    .divide(2));

    stack.translateYProperty()
            .bind(scene.heightProperty().subtract(stack.heightProperty())
                    .divide(2));
```

Add this stack to root element:

```
root.getChildren().add(stack);
```

Show `primaryStage` and execute other code in your start method:

```
primaryStage.show();
```

Comment: https://github.com/BITPlan/com.bitplan.javafx/blob/master/src/test/java/com/bitplan/javafx/stackoverflow/StackedImageViewTest.java has this code embedded in a TestApplication to show the effect

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to make small images dynamically centered :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class CenterInStage extends Application {

    private final String TITLE = "Center in Stage";
    private final double WIDTH = 350;
    private final double HEIGHT = 250;
    private final String IMAGE_PATH =
            "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iconka/meow-2/64/cat-rascal-icon.png";

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setTitle(TITLE);

        Image image = new Image(IMAGE_PATH);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

        StackPane pane = new StackPane();
        pane.getChildren().add(imageView);
        StackPane.setAlignment(imageView, Pos.CENTER);

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: the question is about `AnchorPane`. not `StackPane`!