# how to center an ImageView in a tab JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I want to put an ImageView in the center of a tab (JavaFx), please help me. I use this code to fix margines but ,I can't center the ImageView .

```
ImageView view = new ImageView();
Tab tab = new Tab("Onglet " + (tabs.getTabs().size() + 1));
tab.setContent(view);
view.setTranslateX(100);
view.setTranslateY(100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the ImageView into a [layout pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm) that meets your requirements.

[The answers in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20014787/how-do-i-center-an-image-view-in-an-anchor-pane) may help you as well.

Comment: Thanks it is working now (: